# razorpay.errors.BadRequestError: Amount is/are not required and should not be sent

Tags: django, django-views, payment-gateway, payment, razorpay

> I am integrating razorpay payment gateway in my django project and  dont know why i am getting this error.:-Amount is/are not required and should not be sent.
> i checked my whole code but did not find any solution

> This is Traceback, In traceback window i am getting Exception Value: Amount is/are not required and should not be sent

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Project 3\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\Project 3\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\Project 3\payment\paymentapp\views.py", line 13, in index
    payment = client.order.create({'Amount':amount, 'currency':'INR','payment_capture':'1'})
  File "D:\Project 3\test\lib\site-packages\razorpay\resources\order.py", line 71, in create
    return self.post_url(url, data, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Project 3\test\lib\site-packages\razorpay\resources\base.py", line 20, in post_url
    return self.client.post(url, data, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Project 3\test\lib\site-packages\razorpay\client.py", line 155, in post
    return self.request('post', path, data=data, **options)
  File "D:\Project 3\test\lib\site-packages\razorpay\client.py", line 136, in request
    raise BadRequestError(msg)

Exception Type: BadRequestError at /
Exception Value: Amount is/are not required and should not be sent
```

> This is Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

import razorpay

from .models import coffee 
# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
    Name = request.POST.get("Name")
    amount = int(request.POST.get("Amount")) * 100
    client = razorpay.Client(auth=("rzp_test_YhfEhfejrkkjdkfju","t5MRPkjfijdh23845kejkej"))
    payment = client.order.create({'Amount':amount, 'currency':'INR','payment_capture':'1'})
    print(payment)
    Coffee = coffee(Name=Name, Amount=amount , payment_id = payment['id'] )
    return render(request,'index.html',{'payment':payment})

 return render(request,'index.html')

def success(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    a = request.POST
    print(a)
return render(request,"success.html")
```

> This is Index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} 

{% block content %}
<div class="col-6 mx-auto">
  <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="form-label">Enter Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="Name" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="form-label">Enter Amount</label>
        <input type="number" name="Amount"  class="form-control">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>

{% if payment %}

<div class="text-center mx-auto">
  <form action="/success" method="POST">
    <script
        src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"
        data-key="rzp_test_YhfEhfejrkkjdkfju"
        data-amount="{{payment.Amount}}"
        data-currency="INR" 
        data-order_id="{{payment.id}}"
        data-buttontext="Pay with Razorpay"
        data-name="Coffee Corp"
        data-description="A Wild Sheep Chase is the third novel by Japanese author Haruki Murakami"
        data-image="https://example.com/your_logo.jpg"
        data-prefill.name="Gaurav Kumar"
        data-prefill.email="gaurav.kumar@example.com"
        data-theme.color="#F37254"
    ></script>
    <input type="hidden" custom="Hidden Element" name="hidden">
    </form>

</div> 
{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I think razorpay integration is very much case sensitive, i dont know the technical part why this is with razorpay but this solution is worked for me, What i did
> I change the variable which is taking the **post** data in **lowercase**.

```
def index(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        name = request.POST.get("name")
        amount = int(request.POST.get("Amount")) * 100 # I wrote amount variable in lowercase
        client = razorpay.Client(auth=("rzp_test_YhfE7ZnBpKrrDq","t5MRPBtnWi57MoyjDvV7nJQO"))
        payment = client.order.create({'amount':amount, 'currency':'INR','payment_capture':'1'})
        print(payment)
        Coffee = coffee(name=name, amount=amount , payment_id = payment['id'] )#In this also i used lowercase for variables.
        return render(request,'index.html',{'payment':payment})

    return render(request,'index.html')


def success(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        a = request.POST
        print(a)
    return render(request,"success.html")
```